# cast operator to base class within a thin wrapper derived class

Tags: c++, typecast-operator

I have a derived class that's a very thin wrapper around a base class.  Basically, I have a class that has two ways that it can be compared depending on how you interpret it so I created a new class that derives from the base class and only has new constructors (that just delegate to the base class) and a new `operator==`.  What I'd like to do is overload the `operator Base&()` in the Derived class so in cases where I need to interpret it as the Base.

For example:

```
class Base
{
  Base(stuff);
  Base(const Base& that);
  bool operator==(Base& rhs); //typical equality test
};

class Derived : public Base
{
  Derived(stuff) : Base(stuff) {};
  Derived(const Base& that) : Base(that) {};
  Derived(const Derived& that) : Base(that) {};
  bool operator==(Derived& rhs); //special case equality test
  operator Base&()
  {
    return (Base&)*this;  //Is this OK?  It seems wrong to me.
  }
};
```

If you want a simple example of what I'm trying to do, pretend I had a String class and `String==String` is the typical character by character comparison.  But I created a new class `CaseInsensitiveString` that did a case insensitive compare on `CaseInsensitiveString==CaseInsensitiveString` but in all other cases just behaved like a String.  it doesn't even have any new data members, just an overloaded `operator==`.  (Please, don't tell me to use std::string, this is just an example!)

Am I going about this right?  Something seems fishy, but I can't put my finger on it.

Comment: I hope in your actual code, you have a virtual destructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your `Derived` is derived from `Base` publically, your `Derived` is already convertible to `Base &`. There's no need to implement anything extra.

Moreover, when it comes to conversion operator itself, whether you are doing it right or wrong is a moot question, since your conversion operator will never be used anyway. The derived-to-base conversion is always handled by the built-in means. If you provide your own operator for the conversion (as you do above) it will be ignored anyway.

I don't get though how you were planning to use if to solve the original problem with different comparison approaches.

Comment: Yup, you're right.  Can't believe I missed that.  I do this all the time and for some reason I didn't see it today.

Answer (score 2):

Since you use public inheritance, C++ will automatically do the conversion you're trying to implement. There's no need to do it yourself.

However I don't think this is necessarily a good use of inheritance. You're just using it here without any virtual functions, and just to effectively compose the child class. In general derive classes to change behavior, not to reuse it.

Better I think would be to simply create an external algorithm. Due to the lack of virtual functions you can't substitute by base pointer/reference anyway, so instead of converting to a derived class to force the explicit comparison, just call a (possibly friend) standalone method to do the case insensitive comparison. You can even pass the algorithm around (using a functor) if you need to dynamically change it at runtime.